# Базовая логика экранов в рамках Clean Architecture

Tags: android, архитектура

Есть n фрагментов, на каждом из них необходимо отображать информацию о `Relationship` (online status, relationship name, users count). До этого загрузка была вынесена в `BaseFragment` (запрос к базе реализован с помощью `Single`).  Но как эту же логику реализовать в рамках Clean Architecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно подходу Чистой архитектуры, ваша бизнес логика должна быть выделена в UseCase или интерактор. Однако, вы можете переиспользовать один и тот же интерактор для работы с некоторой сущностью, в вашем случае, Relationship, который внутри себя будет иметь репозиторий, в котором и будет описана сетевая логика и логика кеширования.

Если у фрагментов есть своя логика, у них будут свои интеракторы-фасады. Эти интеракторы могут содержить один "общий" интерактор, описанный выше. Инстанс этого интерактора с нужным скоупом вы можете внедрить в туда, где он нужен.

Таким образом, логика вызова и первичной обработки модели будет в одном месте.

Данный подход избавляет вас от стандартной проблемы наследования. Если у одного из фрагментов будет несколько "базовых" сущностей, то вместо сложной иерархии наследовании, вы сможете использовать обычную композицию.

Comment: Хороший ответ, ну впринципе автор частично так и делал. Ничего плохого нет если создать свой BaseFragment, в котором будет описана собственная Ui логика, здесь нет проблем в наследовании. Делаем интерактор - presenter для фрагментов, избавляемся от Ui Independents, база реализована через сингл инстанс SqliteOpenHelper, я так понимаю, выноси туда же, пускай интерфейсы менеджерят состоягия, ну и все будет отдельно хорошо тестироваться, чем не CleanArchitecture?